# Refresh Token using Static HttpClient

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

Using VS 2017 .Net 4.5.2

I have the following class

```
public static class MyHttpClient
{
    //fields
    private static Lazy<Task<HttpClient>> _Client = new Lazy<Task<HttpClient>>(async () =>
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        await InitClient(client).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return client;
    });

    //properties
    public static Task<HttpClient> ClientTask => _Client.Value;

    //methods
    private static async Task InitClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        //resey headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        //Set base URL, NOT thread safe, which is why this method is only accessed via lazy initialization
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddress"]);//TODO: get from web.config? File? DB?
        //create new request to obtain auth token
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/ouath2/token"); //TODO: get from web.config? File? DB? prob consts
        //Encode secret and ID 
        var byteArray = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes($"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"]}:{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]}");
        //Form data
        var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"));
        formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RefreshToken"]));
        //set content and headers
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        //make request
        var result = await HttpPost(request, client).ConfigureAwait(false);
        //set bearer token
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", (string)result.access_token);

        //TODO: error handle
    }

    private static async Task<dynamic> HttpPost(HttpRequestMessage formData, HttpClient client)
    {
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(formData).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();//TODO: handle this

            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Still in progress but I've hit a snag.

This works fine if the token only needs to be fetched once in an applications life, however the API I'm talking to uses short lived bearer tokens (15mins).

As I'm using HttpClient as a static to be reused, I cannot change the Default request headers as they are not threadsafe.  But I'm required to request a Bearer token every 15mins.

How would I achieve obtaining a new bearer token and setting the default header in this particular scenario?

Comment: Normally the refresh token lives longer than the access tokens. If so, a common scenario is to request a new token after receiving a HTTP403. With an http-client, this is easily implemented in a handler. So; do you have an actual refresh token? and, if so; does it last long enough?

Comment: the refresh token is long lived, use it to get a new bearer token, the bearer token is short lived (15mins). i put "refresh" instead of "bearer", typo is fixed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*update: added the SemaphoreSlim to "lock" the refresh transaction*

**disclaimer: not tested, might need some tweaking**

**note 1: the semaphore needs to be in a try/catch/finaly block to ensure release if an error is thrown.**

**note 2: this version will queue the refresh token calls which significant degrades performance if load is high.** To fix this; use a bool indicator to check if the refresh is occurred. This might be a static bool for example

The goal is to only use the refresh token if needed. A fixed interval won't help you because, one day, this interval might change. The correct way to handle this is to retry if a 403 occurs.

You can use a HttpClientHandler to work with your HttpClient.

Override the SendAsync, to handle and retry the 403.

For this to work you'll need this [constructor of httpclient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193664(v=vs.118).aspx):

From the top of my (semi) head, it must be something like this:

**the HttpMessageHandler**

```
public class MyHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private static SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {  
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    //test for 403 and actual bearer token in initial request
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized &&
        request.Headers.Where(c => c.Key == "Authorization")
                .Select(c => c.Value)
                .Any(c => c.Any(p => p.StartsWith("Bearer"))))
        {

            //going to request refresh token: enter or start wait
            await sem.WaitAsync();

            //some typical stuff
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", yourRefreshToken),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", yourApplicationId),
            };

            //retry do to token request
            using ( var refreshResponse = await base.SendAsync(
                new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
                   new Uri(new Uri(Host), "Token")) 
                   { 
                      Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs) 
                   }, cancellationToken))
            {
                var rawResponse = await refreshResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RefreshToken>(rawResponse);

                //new tokens here!
                //x.access_token;
                //x.refresh_token;

                //to be sure
                request.Headers.Remove("Authorization");
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + x.access_token);

                //headers are set, so release:
                sem.Release();  

                //retry actual request with new tokens
                response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
}
```

**send example, with SendAsync (could also be GetAsync) etc.**

```
public async Task<int> RegisterAsync(Model model)
{
    var response = await YourHttpClient
       .SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(BaseUri, "api/Foo/Faa"))
    {  
        Content = new StringContent(
           JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model),
           Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    });

    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: im using postasync and getasync methods of httpclient.  Woudl it make more sense to instead use sendasync and use requestmessage instead? is setting the requestmessage headers thread safe?

Comment: For your `HttpClient`: `PostAsync`, `GetAsync` etc, are just facade/wrapper methods for `SendAsync`, so, `GetAsync/PostAsync` are fine. The `RequestMessage` is thread safe since, in a way, it's local. I'll extend the example a bit

Comment: looking through first time should work, goes through, fails auth, goes and gets new token and try's again, succeeds and returns.  1min later a new request is done as per your example, but again no bearer token exists, because we only changed the bearer on the individual request? or am i reading this wrong?

Comment: if all goes well, on a 403, you'll get a new access token **and** a new refresh token at the `new tokens here!` line. You should store them and use them in subsequent requests, access tokens for general requests, refresh token for refresh token request.

Comment: "You should store them and use them in subsequent requests" thats my point how would i do this as request is new request in my calling method, and i cant use default headers as per the question?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you but, you are using  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RefreshToken"]` for the refresh token, I would assume you can write this value as well. You could do the same for the access token (although both should be kept secret). You can also store it in memory, or in your MyHttpClient object. If your question is about where to apply the headers; normally in your calling function because, possibly, not all API calls need this authorization. You can also override the `SendAsync` to automatically apply those headers, but you'll need to get the token from somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166958/discussion-between-lemunk-and-stefan).

Comment: @lemunk: I posted an update, but havn't tested it, since I am in a bit of a hurry. I'll check it later, but it should give you some directions.

Comment: issue is once a response has been obtained you cannot resend the same request. so the very last part where we effectively retry, we get a 500 internal instead as the response due to the attempted resend

Comment: Hmm.. that's strange. Are you sure you set the new access token in the header?

Comment: yeh its because we get the response to perform checks, so Ive created some extension method to clone the request. just tweaking and testing

Comment: Yes, the trick is to re-use the initial request (or use an exact copy) with the new headers. Although it strikes me ass odd since I have used this in several scenarios

Comment: well i have it working although not fully tested, (aint no TDD method on this) so im happy with it. thanks for the help

Comment: Good to hear that you found a way. And remember, thanks is expressed by up-voting ;-) XD

Comment: got you covered dude ;)

Comment: @Stefan, regarding your 2nd note "use a `bool` indicator to check if the refresh is occurred. This might be a `static bool` for example" - I'm not sure where the check should occur. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Should not you make your SemaphoreSlim static?

Comment: @IRONicMAN: I think that will make sense indeed :-)