# Getting a Refresh Token from IdentitySever4

Tags: identityserver4, refresh-token, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor web app that connects to a different Identity Server 4 server. I can get the login to work correctly and pass the access token back the Blazor. However, when the token expires I don't know how to go out and get a new access token? Should I be getting a refresh token and then an access token? I am confused on how this all works.

Blazor Code

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
         {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         })
         .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddOpenIdConnect(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
         {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44382";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

            options.ClientId = "client";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token token";
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.Scope.Add("IdentityServerApi");
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("email");
            options.Scope.Add("roles");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
         });
```

IdentityServer4 Setup

```
...
        new Client
         {
            ClientId = "client",
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            RequireClientSecret = true,

            RequireConsent = false,
            RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44370/signin-oidc" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44370/signout-callback-oidc" },
            AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "roles", "offline_access",
               IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName
            },
            AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://localhost:44370" },

            AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,

            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AccessTokenLifetime = 1,//testing
            UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true
         },
...
```

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my code to offline_access for the client and server (thanks for the update below). My next question is how do I inject the request for the refresh token in Blazor once I get rejected because the access token is expired?

I have the Blazor app making calls back to the API (which validates the access token).

```
   public class APIClient : IAPIClient
   {
      private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

      //add the bearer token to the APIClient when the client is used
      public APIClient(IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor, HttpClient client, IConfiguration configuration)
      {
         var accessToken = httpAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
         client.DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0);
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration["Api_Location"]);
         _httpClient = client;
         _logger = logger;
      }
```

What do I need to add to my API calls to validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should obtain a refresh token as well to keep getting new access tokens. To get a refresh token from IdentityServer you need to add the 'offline_access' scope in the 'AllowedScopes' property of your client. You also need to set the 'AllowOfflineAccess' property on your client to true.

After that you need to include 'offline_access' to the scopes sent by the client and you should receive a refresh token in the response.

To use the refresh token, send a request to the token endpoint with everything you sent for the code exchange except replace the 'code' param with 'refresh_token' and change the value for 'grant_type' from 'code' to 'refresh_token'. The IdentityServer4 response to this request should contain an id_token, an access_token, and a new refresh_token.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an answer (given the push from Randy). I did something familiar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304326/refresh-token-using-static-httpclient), where I created a generic method in my APIClient.

```
      public async Task<T> SendAsync<T>(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
      {
         var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
         //test for 403 and actual bearer token in initial request
         if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized &&
             requestMessage.Headers.Where(c => c.Key == "Authorization")
                     .Select(c => c.Value)
                     .Any(c => c.Any(p => p.StartsWith("Bearer"))))
         {
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", _httpAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token").Result),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "someclient"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "*****")
            };

            //retry do to token request
            using (var refreshResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(
                new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(_authLocation + "connect/token"))
                {
                   Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs)})
               )
            {
               var rawResponse = await refreshResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               var x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data.Models.Token>(rawResponse);
               var info = await _httpAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies");

               info.Properties.UpdateTokenValue("refresh_token", x.Refresh_Token);
               info.Properties.UpdateTokenValue("access_token", x.Access_Token);
               _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
               _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", x.Access_Token);

               //retry actual request with new tokens
               response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(requestMessage.Method, requestMessage.RequestUri));

            }
         }
         if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(HttpResponseMessage)))
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(response, typeof(T));
         else
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
      }
```

I don't like that I have to call AuthenticateAsync. Yet, that seems to be the way I have found to get access to the UpdateTokenValue method to delete and then re-add the new access token.