# How to handle token expiration in httpclient?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am in front of problem below.
I am using a httpclient for make requests. Also we use bearer authorization and getting token from server each one hour.
I am trying to find which is the best solution for checking if our token has been expired.

Here is an example from server Response when we generate a token

```
{

 "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBEOEZCOEQ2RURFQ0Y1Qzk3RUY1MjdDMDYxNkJCMjMzM0FCNjVGOUZSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6ImF0K2p3dCIsIng1dC",
 "expires_in": 3600, //seconds
 "token_type": "Bearer",
}
```

1. First solution is to create a static datetime. Then save token expiration datetime in this static datetime.
   Then in each request to compare current datetime with expiration datetime, and if need to generate a new token.

Is there any way to register a method in httpclient? So in each request to run this method first?

We tried to create a static method, and place it before each httpclient request.
But we don't want to copy paste this method before each request. If there is a method to register a method in httpclient

Here is an httpclient example

```
public class HttpClientHelper
{
    private static HttpClient httpClient;
    public static HttpClient Request()
    {
        if (httpClient == null)
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

And here is how you are making a request

```
var uri = "http://myurl.com"; 
using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
            {
                
                using (var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClientHelper.Request().SendAsync(httpRequestMessage,
                  new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Token))
                {
                    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                       
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please update with actual c# code you have tried and the one challenge you have with that.  Quite a few unknowns without some code - for example is this MVC; some app, something else?  Controller?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh Token using Static HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304326/refresh-token-using-static-httpclient)

Comment: _"First solution is to create a static datetime."_ - this will not save from the lag between check and the call or potential different system clock on two machines. You can create custom `HttpHandler` which will retry the requests with failed auth if token has expired.

Comment: Thank you Guru, could you send me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to store the token in local memory cache and set an expiration. When the JWT is about to expire then it should invalidate the cache entry.

```cs
IMemoryCache cache = provider.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();

var token = cache.Get("access_token");
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(token))
{
  return token;
}

var newToken = GetAccessToken();
cache.Set("access_token", newToken, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(55));  // assuming tokens expire in 1hr
```